# What type of hash is this?

Tags: hash, sha

Can anyone help me to find out what type of hash this is? I have it in this form:

`{SHA}vv359MeXQ+GgsEFZpf0No4HXxCg=`

But I don't think it is simply SHA1

I've tried to decode it with an sha1 decryptor on some websites, but that says it is not SHA1.

Answer (score 3):

The length of the base64 value that you posted is 20 bytes (160 bits), so it very well could be a SHA1 hash, as SHA1 hashes are 160 bits in length.

The 20 bytes that you posted in base64 format equate to the following in hexadecimal format:

```
be fd f9 f4 c7 97 43 e1 a0 b0 41 59 a5 fd 0d a3 81 d7 c4 28
```

Comment: I've tried to decode as base64, but i just get an unreadable text, it doesn't really seem an hashed string, and i tried many different source charsets..

Comment: @erjay you need to hexdump the base64 decode output: `echo vv359MeXQ+GgsEFZpf0No4HXxCg= | base64 -d | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"' ; echo`

Comment: Or, `echo -n "vv359MeXQ+GgsEFZpf0No4HXxCg=" | base64 -d | xxd -c 20` works as well.  With regard to, `' I just get an unreadable text, it doesn't really seem an hashed string'` - the output of a hash function should be akin to randomly generated bytes, by design.  What makes you think that the hash that you posted in your question could not be a hashed string?

Comment: @erjey: *...I just get unreadable text...* It isn't text at all, it's the binary output of a hash function.